# Using if else statements for switching user path directories

Tags: python, conditional-statements

```
user = 'ti'
user = 'dy'

import sys

if user=='ti':
    sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\kie\OneDrive - AUA\TO\Space Modeling\Demand Tool')
```

There are two users in one script. To constantly change the path directories is tedious. What kind of `if` or `else` statements can I use so that the paths can easily change from one user to the other instead of manual input?

Comment: How about a `dict`, whose keys are usernames, and whose values are the corresponding paths?

Comment: For future reference: You can use a limited version of markdown to format your questions and answers quite nicely. [Here's some formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @RandomDavis could you give an example on how I would incorporate it?

Comment: @Pear `user_path = {'ti': r'C:\Users\BlahBlah', 'us': 'C:\Something\Whatever'}` and then just `sys.path.append(user_path['ti'])` (after checking `if username in user_path`).